# Toggling background image (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, background, textarea, toggle

```
$('textarea').focus(function() {
    var img = $(this).css('background-image');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
});
$('textarea').blur(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', img);
});
```

.. doesn't seem to work. I think somethings wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define

```
var img
```

just inside the `.focus()` event handler, that variable will not be available within
`.blur()`

So either define `var img` globaly, or use jQuerys `.data()` method for instance.

write:

```
$.data(this, 'img', $(this).css('background-image'));
```

read:

```
$.data(this, 'img');
```

example:

```
$('textarea').focus(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $.data(this, 'img', $this.css('background-image'));
   $this.css('background-image', 'none');
});
$('textarea').blur(function() {
   $(this).css('background-image', $.data(this, 'img') || '');
});
```

Comment: +1 - I would just do `$.data(this, 'img')` though, no need to create a wasted object here.

Comment: @Nick: I didn't know that `$.data()` works with DOM objects, too. nice!

Comment: erm...can you show an example, I can't get it to work. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the url-address for the image in css.

```
var img = 'images/mybg.png';
$('textarea').blur(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url('+img+')');
});
```